# Is there any way to have Google Form responses go to two different Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form setup in a Google Sheet. I want the responses from that form to go that same sheet but also a separate, master Google Sheet. Is this possible?

I can only get it to do one or the other, not both. Would love to find a way to go to both.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en-GB) to have everything copied to your other sheet.